# How to authenticate token in android studio? Auth not recognized?

Tags: android, authentication, localhost, telnet

I want to run telnet localhost 5554 in the terminal of android studio.
However ,when I do it shows me this

```
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'C:\Users\Wajeeha Yasin\.emulator_console_auth_token'
```

I copied the token and when I type it in as

```
 auth <my-token>
```

it says

```
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
```

And nothing happens. I am still unable to use telnet command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That typically means you're now authenticated. To be sure, Try typing "help power" if you get a documentation about power features and usage then you're all set.